# Calculate quantity based on different text values

Tags: php

Good day

I'd be grateful for some expertise with this issue of mine.

Assume we have the following variables in a hypothetical situation:

```
$uom = (either "PLT" or "CRT")
$prow = item ID in cart (starts from 1 and goes up depending on how many items)
$quantity = quantity of each item
$Name = item name
$quantityplt = new variable for PLT quantity
$quantitycrt = new variable for CRT quantity
```

This information is acquired for each product from a cart shopping system on the website. So once the user adds an item to the cart, that information is displayed for each item in the cart that they chose.

I have two text inputs which need to display the total_quantity for all the items: **depending** on whether or not the $uom is "CRT" or "PLT".

```
<input type="text" id="plt_sum" readonly/>
<input type="text" id="crt_sum" readonly/>
```

Now, I need to calculate the $quantity depending on $uom.

It must then display the value in either "#plt_sum" or "#crt_sum"...

I'm not confident in using loops so I don't really know how to:

```
<?php 
foreach($prow){
if($uom=="PLT"){ 
$quantityplt value == (perform $quantity addition WHERE $uom is "PLT");
echo $quantityplt (in the #plt_sum text input);
}
elseif($uom=="CRT"){
$quantitycrt value == (perform $quantity addition WHERE $uom is "CRT");
echo $quantitycrt (in the #crt_sum text input);
}
} 
?>
```

I do hope this piece of php makes any sense at all. I realise my syntax and everything else is most likely wrong. I'm still very new to it and learning things every day.

Thank you for reading and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Good morning, your code is more pseudo-code than PHP itself, there are many syntax issues.  But conceptually, your approach is logical.  You will want to define $prow as a list and use foreach on it.  To get you started in PHP syntax (and concepts), I recommend https://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: Hello. Yes I mostly wanted to outline the logical side of it, so that the final outcome is clear. I just wouldn't know how to use the foreach and list at this time. Thanks for your reply.